# Equal Height Images Using Flexbox without setting any fixed height?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, flexbox, grid

Hello I am trying to make two images the same height with Flexbox in wordpress website.

here is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper > div:first-child {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.wrapper img{
 width:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="img1"><img src="https://hostingstudies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/wordpress-1882120_1280-3.png" />

<p>WordPress is the world’s most popular site builder. It powers more than 33% of all websites on the internet, that’s millions of websites all over the world.</p>
</div>

<div class="img2"><img src="https://hostingstudies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/wordpress-923188_1280-2.jpg" />
<p>WordPress started as a simple blogging platform back in 2003. Since then it has evolved to become a content management system and an application development framework.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why dont you fix a fix height on your img as you did for the width ?

Comment: But I don't want to set a fixed height it breaks my image in smaller screen Is there any way using flexbox ??

Comment: You need to set image in container as I did. If you really cannot, you may have a way with flex usage but more complex

Answer (score 0):

I set an image into a container `img-container` that has a fix height. And in that I set your `img` as below:

```
.img-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper img{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I also set your 2 div img as follow:

```
.img1, .img2{
  width: 50%;
}
```

### Final result:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper > div:first-child {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.img1, .img2{
  width: 50%;
}
.img-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper img{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img1">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://hostingstudies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/wordpress-1882120_1280-3.png" />
    </div>
    <p>WordPress is the world’s most popular site builder. It powers more than 33% of all websites on the internet, that’s millions of websites all over the world.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="img2">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://hostingstudies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/wordpress-923188_1280-2.jpg" />
    </div>
    <p>WordPress started as a simple blogging platform back in 2003. Since then it has evolved to become a content management system and an application development framework.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still breaking my image in smaller screen when I resize the browser

Comment: @Mar Here I corrected with a little `overflow: hidden` trick

Comment: It's not woking for me resize the browser and you will see the problem in height

Comment: @Mar You have to understand that 2 basics images that dont have same basic size wont ever get better than that. I just checked on phone and computer iamge size are always on same line. So I guess if you want to get better you will need to resize and cut manualy your image to get the result you want. But you wont be able to get better

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right maybe it is more complicated with flex box

Comment: Because if you just think about it. If you have 2 images. One landscape and the other portrait. Then your only way to keep photos always 100% height is this one.

Answer (score -1):

I added height of 100px

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper > div:first-child {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.wrapper img{
 width:150px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="img1"><img src="https://hostingstudies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/wordpress-1882120_1280-3.png" />

<p>WordPress is the world’s most popular site builder. It powers more than 33% of all websites on the internet, that’s millions of websites all over the world.</p>
</div>

<div class="img2"><img src="https://hostingstudies.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/wordpress-923188_1280-2.jpg" />
<p>WordPress started as a simple blogging platform back in 2003. Since then it has evolved to become a content management system and an application development framework.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the same height without setting a fixed height Can it be done using flexbox ??

Comment: if the original images does not have equal height then you'll have to set the height, you can't dictate the height with flexbox, flexbox is just for layouts